# Construct XML from XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to generate XML data from a XSD. Particularly, from a given schema a GUI shall be constructed "on the fly", allowing to enter/edit an instance for that schema. Unfortunately, pure XSD is not really suited, to describe, how such GUI must look like.

Q: Is there any generic approch, to construct a GUI from XSD ? Not a final solution, but a way, allowing this by using other tools.

Many Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/) with its [XSD](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd) support and [Graphiti](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/) or [GMF](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial/Part_1) for the GUI.